# Apk not approved by play store (Apk Generated From Android Studio and using Apache Cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, apk

We are using Apache Cordova (Phonegap) to develop android app.

We generate signed apk from Android Studio and published to play store.

Apk rejected by play store and got the response "upgrade your app to Apache Cordova 4.0.0 or higher"

But we have already upgraded our app to Apache Cordova 5.2.2

Note: We generate signed apk from Eclipse and published to play store. Its approved by play store.

Please let us know what is the problem with android studio because we are planning to move eclipse to android studio

Comment: If you can build from the same source one apk (by Eclipse) that gets approved and other (by AS) that does not, then compare the content of those two apk, how they differ. If you did use some eclipse-project import generating new gradle file, it may be the gradle build is using different way to build cordova, maybe some obsolete cordova gradle plugin, etc... so check the gradle files (I *assume* you don't use gradle under Eclipse and let AS automatically import+convert the project). If you are lucky, it may obvious from .apk content what cordova libs are included/etc... what to search for.

Comment: Check also official docs first, if you didn't: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#configuring-gradle  (BTW, I never did use Cordova, so these are just generic troubleshooting suggestions, I have no idea what exactly may be your problem)